# Part of the DAE model becomes transparent in Xcode

Tags: xcode, scenekit, blender, arkit

I am using the DAE model which was exported from 3dsMax into `Blender` software.

[image]

But when I load it into Xcode the right side of it becomes transparent.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is the `Normals` on the right side of your model and they might be facing the wrong way.

The direction of a face is called its `Normal`. Sometimes get face `Normals` going in the wrong direction. It is easy to fix.

Select the face in edit mode then

> Mesh > Normals

[Blender: Edit Mode: Mesh > Normals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQe9y.png)

Hope this helps.

Comment: “Sometimes get face normals going in the wrong direction.” For example, this can happen when a mesh is mirrored which appears to be the case here.