# "dae" 3D model side become transparent in iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, 3d, scenekit, cinema-4d

I'm new to 3D models and try to make my test game in [SceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/)

I use [Cinema 4D](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinema_4D) on Windows PC for creating 3D models.

I want to add my texture with a transparent background on a side of a 3D object.

But my texture makes the cube's side transparent instead of keep as it was.

In Cinema 4D it displays as intended.
[image]

On macOS Preview it looks transparent. The same for launched app on iOS
[image]

In XCode it looks

[image]

[Here is my 3D model(zipped "dae" file)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y3SpEDfgMYFYzaMjwBCdYopTOe6C8Dx-/view?usp=sharing)

I've googled a lot, found some info [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46704313/part-of-the-dae-model-becomes-transparent-in-xcode) but it didn't help.

PS
Thanks for your time. I'm a newkid in 3D games, any advice are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the texture is transparent, which SceneKit interprets as you wanting a non-opaque material. In SceneKit you can't have multiple layers of materials with for instance a transparent image and some other opaque material for the same face. Instead you should use an opaque texture with a background color matching the color of the other faces of the cube.